# Is is possible to use the submit ID value in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

`name="submit"` works normally like it should

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))

<input type="submit" ID="asdf" name="submit" value="Save" class="ui blue mini button">
```

I will like to use the ID element instead

```
if(isset($_POST["asdf"]))

<input type="submit" ID="asdf" name="submit" value="Save" class="ui blue mini button">
```

i dont know how to do this, i have tried `if(isset($_POST["#asdf"]))` no luck

Comment: Why? What's wrong with using the name attribute? (which will be submitted in your form, id attribute will not)

Comment: If you have multiple form or need something other than the name use `<input type="hidden" name="something" value="asdf">`

Answer (score 2):

IDs are not passed in a form submission. You can, however, have multiple `<input type="submit">` fields with different names, and act accordingly.

```
<input type="submit" name="asdf" value="Save" class="ui blue mini button">
```

will give you a `$_POST['asdf']` with value `Save`.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot access the ID of the element in the `$_POST` array, only the name. If you do this:

`print_r( $_POST )`

You will see the key that can be accessed, and their values.